# XPATH - How to select a tr that has several values in the column of the same row in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath

I have a table with multiple rows, and I'm trying to use an xpath to find the one row that contains specific values in each column. For eg..Column 1 has id="transactionDetails" and Column 2 has text="VOICE CALL".

What XPATH should i use to get a row that contains those 2 values in the specific column?

```
<td class="nmy_vtab_D" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
<a id="transactionDetails" onclick="document.TRANSACTION_DETAILS.transactionId.value='0_2780001_5170302';document.TRANSACTION_DETAILS.submit();return false;" href="#">02/26/2014 01:39:26</a>
</td>
<td class="nmy_vtab_D" nowrap="nowrap" align="left">VOICE CALL</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression should work for this task:

```xml
//tr[td[1]/a/@id="transactionDetails" and td[2]/text()="VOICE CALL"]
```

It selects `tr` which first `td` has a `a` tag with id="transactionDetails", **and** the second `td` has a text "VOICE CALL".

Answer (score 0):

The markup you have there represents 2 table cells, one of them containing a link with text of date and other cell is containing text VOICE CALL. The link element contains a ID so you can use that in your xpath to get the entire cell if this is indeed what you need:

```
//a[@id="transactionDetails"]//..
```

For second one you can consider using the text perhaps?

```
//td[text()=="VOICE CALL"]
```

Comment: Yes it works if i have a single row. But in case if more one rows with same ID="transactionDetails", then we need to comapare the second column to locate the correct row.

Comment: Sry, I didn't get the question right. On a side note, HTML element Id's should (must) be unique. _id = name [CS]
    This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document._ [Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) , same goes with HTML5